# BeautifulSoup: Select P tag that comes after another P tag which should contain a link

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The webpage I'm scraping has paragraphs and headings structured this way:

```html
<p>
  <strong>
  <a href="https://dummy.com" class="">This is a link heading
  </strong>
</p>
<p>
  Content To Be Pulled
</p>
```

I wrote the following code to pull the link heading's content:

```py
 for anchor in soup.find_all('#pcl-full-content > p > strong > a'):
    signs.append(anchor.text)
```

The next part is confusing me because the text I want to collect next is the `<p>` tag  *after* the `<p>` tag which contains the link. I cannot use `.next_sibling()` here because it is outside of the parent `<p>` tag.

How do I choose the following paragraph **given that the `<p>` before it contained a link?**

Comment: Is there an actual public url to go with this?

Comment: @QHarr, yes. I'm trying to scrape together a set of horoscopes from news websites for a text-mining project. You can see [one of the pages here](https://indianexpress.com/article/horoscope/weekly-horoscope-june-6-june-12-gemini-cancer-taurus-and-other-signs-check-astrological-prediction-7346080/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way seems to be to extract from script tag though you will need to split the text by horoscope:

```
import requests, re, json

r = requests.get('https://indianexpress.com/article/horoscope/weekly-horoscope-june-6-june-12-gemini-cancer-taurus-and-other-signs-check-astrological-prediction-7346080/',
                  headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})

data = json.loads(re.search(r'(\{"@context.*articleBody.*\})', r.text).group(1))
print(data['articleBody'])
```

---

You could get the horoscopes separately as follows. This dynamically determines which horoscopes are present, and in what order:

```
import requests, re, json

r = requests.get('https://indianexpress.com/article/horoscope/horoscope-today-april-6-2021-sagittarius-leo-aries-and-other-signs-check-astrological-prediction-7260276/',
                  headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})

data = json.loads(re.search(r'(\{"@context.*articleBody.*\})', r.text).group(1))
# print(data['articleBody'])
signs = ['ARIES', 'TAURUS', 'GEMINI', 'CANCER', 'LEO', 'VIRGO', 'LIBRA', 'SCORPIO', 'SAGITTARIUS', 'CAPRICORN', 'AQUARIUS', 'PISCES']
p = re.compile('|'.join(signs))
signs = p.findall(data['articleBody'])

for number, sign in enumerate(signs):
    if number < len(signs) - 1:
        print(re.search(f'({sign}.*?){signs[number + 1]}', data['articleBody']).group(1))
    else:
        print(re.search(f'({sign}.*)', data['articleBody']).group(1))
```

Comment: Do you mean [something like this?](https://pastebin.com/36wMuBeA), this gives me the following error: `AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'`.  [This is one of the pages](https://indianexpress.com/article/horoscope/weekly-horoscope-june-6-june-12-gemini-cancer-taurus-and-other-signs-check-astrological-prediction-7346080/), I need to capture first the zodiac sign and then the associated horoscope.

Comment: I can't view the page. What does the following give you 1) `anchor.find_previous('p').next_sibling.next_sibling`  or 2) `anchor.find_previous('p').next_sibling.text` ?

Comment: The second one gives me the same error while the first one [does return the texts](https://pastebin.com/P1QNXXA7) but also `<img>`and `<div>` tags which will distort the dataset since they don't line up with the headings.

Comment: Oh boy!! What a wonderful piece of work. This doesn't have to rely on finding the appropriate tags anymore. Thank you so much, you've gone much beyond what I had hoped to have answered. This will facilitate collection of data from many more websites, a lot of whom have unstructured pages. With your permission, I would like to link to your username in the acknowledgments when this project does come out. Thank you again!

Comment: What is `group(1)` for? It is causing this error in one of the links: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` ([this](https://indianexpress.com/article/horoscope/horoscope-today-april-6-2021-sagittarius-leo-aries-and-other-signs-check-astrological-prediction-7260276/) link)

Comment: It means the pattern when the error occurs is not matched for that url. I will have a look. I think it is because the month ordering is different?

Comment: I replaced the code and added a try except to see errors and after a few lines, it caused alternating errors. If you're still interested in looking into it, [this is a set of links](https://github.com/thedivtagguy/data/blob/main/links%20indian%20express.csv). The code seems to fail at link #58

Comment: Please try the update. It seems not only is there different ordering of horoscopes, but there can be missing ones. The script should now account for that.